# How scalable is plone/zope in terms of importing terabytes of existing data on a file system?

Tags: python, plone

How scalable is plone/zope in terms of importing terabytes of existing data on a file system? I am using Plone 4.1 and wish to import existing files/images etc on the file system in linux debian.

Comment: How large are the files? What types of files(matters for indexing)? What is the amount of individual files(each file turns into 1 plone object). The amount of objects and the type of matters because that affects the search catalog--even then, there are many things you can do to optimize. Also, there is a product that'll mirror a file system data.

Comment: Import how? How much integration do you need? What kind of access patterns are there going to be? Your question is way to thin on details for us to be able to formulate an answer.

Comment: @vangheem, if you are talking of Products.Reflecto for mirroring, this add-on only shows part of the file system. But we cannot access it to import the files to plone/zope. We need to use maybe transmogrifier/ funnelweb (which I am currently working on). The files may be engineering drawings, architecture drawings,Advertisements. As per the sizes specified by following url: http://www.teqnium.in/images/Storage%20Requirements.pdf, an E size drawing would require 800 thousand bytes. Would like to use it mainly for version control in the organization for uploaded files.

Comment: @user956424: Plone is not a version control or document management system. I'm not sure this is going to be a good fit for you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @MartijnPieters. Which framework do you suggest for the document management system on linux for version control then within an organization with such engineering drawings?

Comment: The files range from 300kB - 600KB documents to CAD files in the range of 20MB - 30MB.

And there is about 3 TB of such data on a NAS.

This has to be imported into Plone, so that we can search for files, set access permissions, put descriptions/tags, etc.

The specific queries are:

Can Plone/Zope handle this volume of data with reasonable performance?Can this data be imported in a batch mode into Plone using a script/program?

Answer (score 1):

Plone can, with appropriate tuning, handle this kind of load, but as Martijn points out above, Plone is not really a document management or versioning solution for large archives of binary files--it is a web content management system first and foremost.  I would consider looking at something like Alfresco.